# My Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 laptop turns off suddenly at random times

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I have a **Dell Inspiron 15R 5521** laptop that is 7 years old now, its running Windows 10.

It just starts to turn off suddenly at random times without any warnings, when I power on again, starts running fine.

It doesn't turn off when I run many apps, its completely random.

The Event Logger shows **"The previous system shutdown was unexpected"** error

Here is what I have tried

1. Removed battery, changed power adapter as well
2. Cleaned up its fan
3. Tried to shake and move laptop but it doesn't turn off, thinking maybe something loose inside
4. Been using cooling pad since I bought laptop, and laptop doesn't see to be heated at all
5. Tried connecting power adapter to other outlets in home thinking it might be sparking issue
6. Laptop stays on table always, I use external keyboards and mouse, that again eliminates the chance that something is loose inside

EDIT:

Just ran Dell Diagnostics for hardware issues and seems to be no problem

[image: First test]

[image: Second test]

I left my laptop in that test mode all night over and it did not turn off

Ran **TDSSKiller (Kaspersky)** and found 0 threats

Comment: Given all the things you tried, look for a root kit virus.  TDSSKiller (Kaspersky).

Comment: Another thing to try is the Dell Hardware Diagnostic App to look for hardware errors.

Comment: 1. Also, check current consumption of fan, if USB powered -- run without external fan, to see if that helps.  2. Check if the HDD or OS is a problem by booting and running from USB, rather than HDD, e.g., with a Ubuntu Live USB, https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows . If that works for some time without issue, look to the HDD or reinstalling the OS. 3. Reseat RAM cards and, overnight, perform RAM test: https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/

Comment: @John see my edited question, added few details